# Chained select with the second <select> preselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

There is a chained select example at http://jsfiddle.net/LZhQ8:

```
<select id="firstSelect">
<option value="blah1">Blah1</option>
<option value="blah2">Blah2</option>
<option value="blah3">Blah3</option>
</select>

<select id="secondSelect">
</select>

var options = {
blah1: ["A", "B", "C"],
blah2: ["D", "E", "F"],
blah3: ["G", "G", "I"]
};
$(function(){
$('#firstSelect').change(function() {
    var x= $('#firstSelect :selected').val();
    $('#secondSelect').html("");
    for(index in options[x]) {
        $('#secondSelect').append('<option value="' + options[x][index] + '">' + options[x][index] + '</option>')
    };
});})
```

One of the options is shown in the first  dropdown but the options for the second dropdown aren't shown until something is selected in the first.

I would like to have the options in the second dropdown already there depending on what is "selected='selected'" in the first dropdown.

Can such a thing be done?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to just trigger your existing change handler by chaining a call to `.change()` on the end (where `.change()` with no arguments is a shortcut for `.trigger('change')`):

```js
var options = {
blah1: ["A", "B", "C"],
blah2: ["D", "E", "F"],
blah3: ["G", "G", "I"]
};
$(function(){
  $('#firstSelect').change(function() {
    var x= $('#firstSelect').val();
    $('#secondSelect').html("");
    for(index in options[x]) {
        $('#secondSelect').append('<option value="' + options[x][index] + '">' + options[x][index] + '</option>')
    };
  }).change();   // <---- ADD THIS
;})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="firstSelect">
<option value="blah1">Blah1</option>
<option value="blah2" selected>Blah2</option>
<option value="blah3">Blah3</option>
</select>

<select id="secondSelect">
</select>
```

As an optional extra, I've changed `$('#firstSelect :selected').val()` to `$('#firstSelect').val()` because you can get the currently selected value of a (single-select) select element directly, you don't have to go via the selected option element.

Comment: That works! I found though that I had to change the 'optional extra' back to what it was otherwise nothing happened when I selected.

Comment: That's weird - it works fine for me in the runnable snippet in my answer, and is the way that I always get the currently selected value from a select element. (Noting that jQuery isn't doing anything special here: in plain JS, `document.getElementById('firstSelect').value` also works.)